# Insert LineItem in an Opportunity with Apex

Tags: apex

I am trying to add an OpportunityLineItem to an Opportunity and having some challenge with PricebookEntry.

Here is my Apex function:

public static void saveRecord(List recList3){

```
List<PricebookEntry> pbes = [SELECT Id, PriceBook2Id, Product2Id, Product2.Id, Product2.Name FROM PriceBookEntry WHERE Product2Id IN: recList3 AND PriceBook2.isActive=true LIMIT 1];

    for(Integer y = 0, aValue = recList3.size(); y < aValue; y++){
        OpportunityLineItem oli = recList3[y];
        oli.PriceBookEntryId = pbes.Id;
    }
   
    insert recList3;
}
```

My Apex function receives a List of OpportunityLineItems Object
like this:

```
[{"Name":"ProductXYZ","OpportunityId":"0068A000009sx4UQAQ","Product2Id":"01t6g000000R2L4AAK","Quantity":"1","UnitPrice":"1"}]
```

What I need is to go through my OpportunityLineItems List, do a SOQL to find the PricebookEntryId that matches the Product2Id and add it to recList3.

I have 2 errors:
-Invalid bind expression type of OpportunityLineItem does not match domain of foreign key
-Variable does not exist: Id

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, before you can add OpportunityLineItems, you need to assign a value to `Opportunity.Pricebook2Id`. The Salesforce UX does this all for you behind the scenes when you add Opportunity products (because the dialog prompts you for the Pricebook)

But, if you are doing this in Apex, then you have to do the steps manually, 1x1

```
Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Name = 'xx',
                                Stagename = 'ss',
                                CloseDate = Date.today(),
                                Pricebook2Id = thePricebook2Id
                               );
 insert o;

 OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(
                                  OpportunityId = o.Id,
                                  Quantity = qty,
                                  PricebookEntryId = thePricebookEntryId
                                 );
 insert oli;
```

where `thePricebookEntryId` is the ID of the junction record (`PricebookEntry`) that links the PriceBook2 corresponding to the Opportunity's Pricebook2Id and the Product2 (for the SKU of the OpportunityLineItem)

Comment: Hi @cropredy, I was editing my post at the same time so it changes a bit. The opportunity I am in already exist. I am adding oli from a component I created. If I look at your code, I will need to update the opp with thePricebook2Id that I am not sure where to get than add my lineItem. To get the PBE I need to SOQL that object and matches with the Product2Id no?

Comment: Yes, the PricebookEntry will need to be queried to get its Id : `SELECT Id FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id = theIdofthePricebook2 AND Product2Id = theIdOftheProduct2`

Comment: Got it! Not sure this is the right way to do so but it works. I don't like putting a SOQL inside a loop and setting a list all the time. Do you have a better way?
for(Integer y = 0, aValue = recList3.size(); y < aValue; y++){
            OpportunityLineItem oli = recList3[y];
            List<PricebookEntry> pbe = [SELECT Id FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id = '01s6g0000037ZybAAE' AND Product2Id =: recList3[y].Product2Id];
            oli.PriceBookEntryId = pbe[0].Id;
        }
       
        insert recList3;

Comment: don't do soql in a for loop -- build a map of the necessary PBEs before you start constructing the OLIs

Comment: another question (last) :) normally, when creating an opp, you add lineItems, create a quote and sync, the quote will take the products from the opp and create quotelineitems, If you add a quotelineitem, it will add it to the opps because is it sync. My solution deletes the opportunitylineitems when trying to sync :( any idea why?

Comment: Please post your last comment as a new Question and decide if the above answer addressed your initial question.